# JSON Data is not coming from Controller to AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, spring-mvc, google-visualization

Json data that is there in Controller is Not getting in Success function as it is saying that  "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable)" in the browser or Error function is executing...
can any one help me

**AJAX Call**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  alert("I am okay");
  function drawChart () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "index.html",
            type:'get',
            headers: { 
                'Accept': 'application/json', 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
            },
            //dataType: "json",
            success: function (jsonData) {
                alert("Success..............");
                alert(jsonData.jData);
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                // assumes "word" is a string and "count" is a number
                data.addColumn('number', 'Year');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Profit');
                alert("inside.....");
                alert(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) 
                {
                    data.addRow([jsonData[i].profit, jsonData[i].sales, jsonData[i].year, jsonData[i].expenses]);
                }
                alert(data);
                var options = {
                    title: 'Company Details',
                };
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('Chart_div'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            },
        error: function(e)
        { 
            alert('Error: ' + e);
           }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index",method = RequestMethod.GET,headers = {"Content-type=application/json"})
@ResponseBody 
public JSONArray getshowempPage() throws SQLException, JSONException
{ 
    JSONArray jData=gservice.GraphData();
    System.out.println(jData.toString());
    //Here i am getting This result
        jData = [{"profit":"200","sales":"2000","year":"2014","expenses":"400"},{"profit":"250","sales":"1170","year":"2015","expenses":"460"}]
    return jData;
}
```

Thanks in Advance.....

Comment: To make it simple you could remove from your ajax call the attribute headers and also from your Controller. Spring will handle the request correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  alert("I am okay");
  function drawChart () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.html',
            type:'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (jsonData) {
                alert("Success..............");
                alert(jsonData.jData);
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                // assumes "word" is a string and "count" is a number
                data.addColumn('number', 'Year');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Profit');
                alert("inside.....");
                alert(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) 
                {
                    data.addRow([jsonData[i].profit, jsonData[i].sales, jsonData[i].year, jsonData[i].expenses]);
                }
                alert(data);
                var options = {
                    title: 'Company Details',
                };
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('Chart_div'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            },
        error: function(e)
        { 
            alert('Error: ' + e);
           }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you , But still not getting.